# Crop area from image wih OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I want to crop rectangle from my image. I assumed that Point p1 is the top-left corner of the crop rectangle and Point p4 is the bottom-right corner of the rectangle.

The problem is that the compiler is giving me error:
**error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int**

Here's my code:

```
String image = "myPhoto.jpg";
Mat myPhoto = Imgcodecs.imread(image);
Point p1 = new Point(300, 150);
Point p4 = new Point(400, 200);
Rect rectCrop = new Rect(p1.x, p1.y), (p4.x-p1.x+1), (p4.y-p1.y+1));
Mat outputPhoto = myPhoto.submat(rectCrop);
```

I don't have any idea what's here incorrect?

**EDIT:**
I did Clean and Build and error changed to this:
error: -> expected
Rect rectCrop = new Rect((p1.x, p1.y), (p4.x-p1.x+1), (p4.y-p1.y+1));

Comment: what does the error message mean to you? what *siblings* of the types `Point` and `Rect` can you find in OpenCV (use docs.opencv.org)? these identifiers are aliases, for what?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I added error message photo of Netbeans

Comment: don't post images of text. post the text itself. -- at least in C++, Point is Point2i which is a point of integers, and Rect is Rect2i which is also integers... so this error shouldn't have happened. I hope the java API isn't different from that... why would those terms in the constructor evaluate to doubles, not integers?